# Open company data for the Netherlands

Tags: data-request, europe, companies

The [Dutch company register at kvk.nl](http://kvk.nl) doesn't have an API.

Where can I find open company data for the Netherlands? Ideally with an API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[openkvk](https://openkvk.nl/) is a project to provide Dutch company data. The project has been running since 2009 and there's a mature API.

Answer (score 8):

The OpenCorporates project at https://opencorporates.com/ has more than 2.5 million entries for companies registered in the Netherlands as well: https://opencorporates.com/companies/nl

APIs and developer information for the project can be found at http://api.opencorporates.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you search on RapidAPI for "Netherlands company data", you'll see some APIs that offer access to the KVK in Netherlands, for example https://rapidapi.com/appaio/api/netherlands-company-data/